# 我学了中文了 - is it a good sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is 我学了中文了 a good sentence? Is it possible to have 2 times 了 this way?

Are both of the following correct?

- 我学中文了
- 我学了中文

Is their combination also correct?

- 我学了中文了

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to convey? I can only imagine these as answers to, “Did you study Chinese today?” and/or “what did you study today?”

Comment: @Mo. Independently of what I am trying to say, I would like to know if they are meaningfully gramatically well-formed sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"我学中文" - "I learn Chinese"

"我学了中文" - "I've learned Chinese" [了 after a verb is a verb particle that indicates the verb is completed]

*"我学中文了" - Depend on context, it can Imply "我(開始)学中文了" (I have started to learn Chinese) or "我(肯)学中文了" (I am willing to learn Chinese now).  了 after a verb phrase is a verb particle that indicates a change of situation. (change from not learning Chinese to learning Chinese or from unwilling to willing)*

In "我学了中文了" (I've learned Chinese), the first 了 is a verb particle and the second 了 is a final particle.

A final particle is a particle placed at the end of a sentence to (a) indicate the sentence has ended (b) soften the tone of speech (c) to stress the sentence itself or add emotional tone to it.

"我学了中文了" is a valid sentence

Comment: imo, 我学了中文了 would sound more like "I've been learning Chinese (for some time now)" though and 我学了中文 would be "I've learned Chinese".

Answer (score 3):

This is typical perfect-continuous in Mandarin:  V + 了 + ... + 了。  我学了中文了。 I have been learning Chinese.  Usually, there is a duration (length of time) complement:  我学了中文三个月了。  I have been leaning Chinese for 3 months.  ... "and still going on" is the center chore in this pattern.